# Why deep learning can not recgonize this data pattern?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have my X data like this:

```
x = np.random.randint(1,12,(10000,30))
if the x data Meet all following conditions，Corresponding y-value asgin 1,otherwise 0：
1.x[anyrows,0:9] have Three consecutive increasing numbers like 1,5,6 or 2,3,9
2.x[anyrows,10:19] have Three consecutive decreasing numbers like 10,6,5
3.x[anyrows,19:29] have Three consecutive increasing numbers like 5,7,9
```

I trained above x and y into deeplearning using keras,and found the model can not recgnize the pattern and not able to make right prediction of the y value, I dont know why,Is there any algorithm suitable for such a problem?

Below is the detailed class,function:Produce_Final is used to produce the data:

class ProduceData:

```
def __init__(self,new_name="Coner"):
    self.name = new_name
    print('Produce Data Initianized,my name is %s' % self.name)

def Produce_continues_up(self,start,end,xshape0,xshape1):
    x1 = np.random.randint(start,end,(xshape0,xshape1))
    y1 = np.zeros((x1.shape[0], 1), int)
    for lineindex in range(x1.shape[0]):
        for i in range(x1.shape[1] - 2):
            if x1[lineindex, i] < x1[lineindex, i + 1] < x1[lineindex, i + 2]:
                y1[lineindex] = 1
                break

    return x1,y1

def Produce_continues_down(self,start,end,xshape0,xshape1):
    x1 = np.random.randint(start,end,(xshape0,xshape1))
    y1 = np.zeros((x1.shape[0], 1), int)
    for lineindex in range(x1.shape[0]):
        for i in range(x1.shape[1] - 2):
            if x1[lineindex, i] > x1[lineindex, i + 1] > x1[lineindex, i + 2]:
                y1[lineindex] = 1
                break

    return x1,y1

def Produce_Final(self,start,end,xshape0,xshape1,train_data_rate):
    x1, y1 = self.Produce_continues_up(start, end, xshape0, xshape1)
    x2, y2 = self.Produce_continues_down(start, end, xshape0, xshape1)
    x3, y3 = self.Produce_continues_up(start, end, xshape0, xshape1)
    x = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3), axis=1)
    y = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 1), int)
    z = np.concatenate((y1, y2, y3), axis=1)
    for i in range(z.shape[0]):
        if z[i].all(): y[i] = 1

    num = np.int(y.size * train_data_rate)
    X_train = x[:num]
    X_test = x[num:]
    y_train = y[:num]
    y_test = y[num:]

    return X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data are higly inballanced:
0 - 6 % of set
1 - 94 % of set

I suggest to use  class_weight parameter if fit method.

Comment: The result depend on pattern in time so you can try 1D convolution layer or RNN, You can try different metric  because accuracy is not good for imballanced data